# How to properly import subclass frameworks into projects

Tags: swift, frameworks, subclass

I have a question regarding importing subclasses into projects. We often find useful subclasses on GitHub that we can use. In my case it's just a Swift Xcode project which is a Swift port of an Objective-C subclass.

Contains what you see below.

There's no storyboard or anything so I'm wondering why the product folder at the bottom has a SiriWaveformView.framework suitcase icon but there is no framework with this name in the Finder.

Is this technically a framework/API? Do I simply copy SiriWaveformView.swift and SiriWaveformView.h into my own project? How do I connect an interface object to this class?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which of the several questions did you expect someone to answer?  Please try to focus on a single issue.

Comment: They're one in the same. They all have to do with how I bring this subclass into my project and connect to it. They are not separate.